Restoring stdin after dup2 without using fflush is inconsistent
I am trying to understand how duping works in c. I tried to save the file descriptor to stdin so it can be recovered then used dup2 to use file in.txt as input and then use dup2 to return stdin to its original state.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    int stdin_copy = dup(STDIN_FILENO); 

    int input_fd = open("in.txt", O_RDONLY);

    dup2(input_fd, STDIN_FILENO);
    close(input_fd);

    char input_string[100];
    scanf("%s", input_string);
    printf("String from file: %s\n", input_string);

    //fflush(stdin);

    dup2(stdin_copy, STDIN_FILENO);

    printf("Enter a string: ");
    fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", input_string);
    printf("String from terminal: %s\n", input_string);

    return 0;
}

The code was not working properly and scanned the second string from the in.txt file instead of from the terminal until I fixed it with the commented line fflush(stdin). I read that using fflush for stdin is undefined and shouldn't be used so I am wandering why does it even work and what can I replace it with.
Output without fflush(stdin) line:
String from file: 1_line_from_in
Enter a string: String from terminal: 2_line_from_in

And with fflush(stdin):
String from file: 1_line_from_in
Enter a string: line_from_terminal
String from terminal: line_from_terminal


Note that fflush(stdin) is undefined behaviour. Function fflush() is only valid with an output stream. Why does it work? Perhaps your compiler implements it. Note that flushing an input stream renders redirecting input from a file impossible. Note too that undefined does not mean will not work.

Please see Undefined, unspecified and implementation-defined behavior.


fflush(stdin) being undefined doesn't mean that it never works, just that it doesn't have to. 2) Why not use fscanf for the file, instead of redirecting stdin?


@BoP I tried to isolate my problem from a bigger project where I am building my own shell and am trying to implement out operators for builtin commands. The functions I am calling are already designed to read from stdin and stdout so I have to redirect the input. I am trying not to use undefined behaviour but i dont know how to do it otherwise.

When scanf is called, the runtime reads a bunch of data from the file.  If the file is small, it probably reads all of it.  Then it parses some of the data and populates the variables whose addresses were passed to scanf.  The next time you call scanf, it doesn't read any more data; it just parses the data previously read.  If you 've changed the underlying file descriptor, clearly that will have no impact on the second call.  By calling fflush (on systems that support that on stdin), you discard the buffer and force a new read from the underlying file descriptor.

... and the same thing works in the other direction, too: a function that reads from stdin, including implicitly, will read any already-buffered data before it reads from the altered underlying file descriptor.  That can affect you even after a fork, because although the child will get its own copy of each FILE's buffer, each will contain a copy of the parent buffer's contents.

The way to avoid this problem is for your shell to use raw, single-byte read()s, consistently, instead of stdio functions.  This is effectively required by POSIX for shell operation, and even though you're probably not going for POSIX conformance, you're going to have a lot of trouble with redirection, script and subshell execution, and perhaps other things if you go in a different direction.
